# Octokit: add_contents without pushing to repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-api, octokit

I am frequently getting an `Octokit::AbuseDetected` error because my app triggers too many API requests.

I am using the `add_contents` method to add each file inside of a specific directory to a remote repository: (one by one)

```
Dir.glob(wrapper + '/**/*') do |path|
    octokit_client.create_contents(repo, path.sub("#{wrapper}/", ''), 'adding content', File.read(path), branch: 'master') unless File.directory?(path)
end
```

Is there a way to either push all files inside of a directory to a remote repo at once or to first add the contents locally and then push the repo?

Comment: Do you need to use oktokit library? Or it will be OK to switch to the other library, for example [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git)

Comment: @Hirurg103 Well, if it does not make things too complicated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible with oktokit library. To achieve this with [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) you can do the following:

```
Dir.glob(wrapper + '/**/*') do |path|
  next if File.directory?(path)
  File.write path.sub("#{wrapper}/", ''), File.read(path)
end

g = Git.open('.') # initialize ruby git
g.add
g.commit('adding content')
g.push
```

You do not need to authenticate with `ruby-git` in source code. You need to set up ssh-keys - read [Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)

Comment: What does `Git.open('.')` mean? & how do I authenticate to push?